# iMac [2012] crashed while update to iso Catalina

Tags: catalina, imac, software-update, crash, reboot

Try to update my 2012 iMac to Catalina, unluckily it crashed during updated.  it crashed after it already downloaded the new iso. Try to switch on and it goes to white screen and seem the mac is still trying to finished the update.   However, after a 100 hours run, the bar mentions is not even 1/4 is finished.  Try to boot up in safe mode, the apple logo appear and then seem the Mac still wanna finish the installing task.  Apple logo appear again and then the white screen back again and said Mac will restart after finished.

I have back up all data. I don't mind whatever version of iso is running.  I just like to have the Mac can boot up and use as normal.  Should i wait another 100+ hours for it to finish the installation?

Hope you guys can give me some advice. Thanks all!

Comment: Where did you get the ISO from? Can you boot into a recovery mode still?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I did last time it didn't work, but i just try now again. and the recovery mode screen did appear.  It runs now and recover with the time machine. Thank you so much!

Comment: Unlucky again, after try to back up from time machine, iMac hang with message of problem with connection with back up harddisk. Sad